# React Native numberOfLines invalid props.style key

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a formatted TextView like this:

```
headerTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    numberOfLines: 2,
    marginRight: 90
},
```

However, when I run the app, I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `NumberOfLines` supplied to `ForwardRef`.
Bad object: {
  "fontSize": 12,
  "numberOfLines": 2,
  "marginRight": 90
}
```

I tried removing numberOfLines from headerTextStyle and applying it to the parent `View`'s style however in both cases, if the text exceeds 1 line, it doesn't get cut off with ellipsize but instead overflows to the next line.

Answer (score 6):

I think numberOfLines isn't for style but set in the view itself like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Text style={styles.headerTextStyle} 
          numberOfLines={2}>{this.title}</Text>
  )
}
```

this would set the maximum number of lines for the text to 2